# How to use containers.Map to save cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, cell

I have several cell arrays which consist of unequal unequal length of arrays, for example

```
a = {[0]; [1 2]; [3 4 5]};
b = {[1 2 3]; [0 3]};
```

and I want to save these cells into a JSON-like or map-like object in MATLAB that can be visited by keys. Keys can be numbers. For example I'd like to get `a` if I call `c(1)` and get `b` if I call `c(2)`.

`containers.Map` object may be useful but the value type of it cannot be cell arrays.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: How about `c = {a, b}`? Then you can access `a` with  `c{1}` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `containers.Map`, as the value type can be any type:

> Character vector that specifies the data type for the values. Possible
>   values are 'any', 'char', 'logical', 'double', 'single', 'int8',
>   'uint8', 'int16', 'uint16', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', or 'uint64'.
>
> Default: 'any' when you create an empty Map object or when you specify
>   values of different sizes or types, otherwise determined by the data
>   type of valueSet.

With a default `Map` ...

```
map = containers.Map();
map('1') = a;
map('2') = b;
```

.. and get the values:

```
>> map('1')

ans = 

    [         0]
    [1x2 double]
    [1x3 double]
```

If you want the keys to be numbers, you can define the key type in the constructor ...

```
map  = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
map(1) = a;
map(2) = b;
```

... and get the values:

```
>> map(2)

ans = 

    [1x3 double]
    [1x2 double]
```

Comment: It surely does, I've forgotten to set the `valueType`.